# Which convergence to use when showing no-mean-ergodicity?

Tags: time-series, self-study, convergence, ergodic

This is a basic econometrics question about ergodicity.

According to Hamilton, we say that the stationary time series $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$, , with mean $\mu$, is mean ergodic if the following converge in probability holds:
\begin{equation}\label{a}\tag{M-E}
\hat{\mu}_T := \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T X^t \overset{p}{\to} \mu
\end{equation}

But, others define ergodicity when the converge in \ref{a} holds for other convergence. For example, [here (slide 14)](https://www.lem.sssup.it/phd/documents/Lesson6.pdf) the author uses quadratic mean, and [here (slide 5)](https://web.pdx.edu/%7Ecrkl/ec571/ec571-tsa.pdf), almost sure convergence.

I know well that quadratic mean convergence and almost sure congergence, each one, implies convergence in probability.  So I have no problem defining mean-ergodicity using quadratic mean  convergence or almost sure.

The problem is when it comes to showing that a certain process is not mean-ergodicity. For example, in the [same lecture (slides 19 and 20)](https://www.lem.sssup.it/phd/documents/Lesson6.pdf) given above, it shows that it is not mean-ergodic by showing that quadratic mean convergence does not hold. However, it may still hold convergence in probability. I didn't check if in this case the convergence in probability doesn't hold too, but wouldn't it be better to prove the non-convergence in probability to avoid these cases? Which convergence to use when showing no-men-ergodicity?

Comment: I can think of like three other definitions you haven’t mentioned, too. You just gotta pick one and stick with it

Comment: But this is not very strict. As I mentioned above, if you use quadratic mean convergence and I use probability convergence we will have a conflict: for you something may not be mean-ergodic and I may have the ergodicity. Wouldn't that be bad?

Comment: yes, it's bad because it's confusing and more difficult to apply/discuss theorems